# check if a contains specific text

Tags: jquery, html

I need to check if inside `a` tags, contains specific text

I am using this kind of code, but it return success message every time.

```
if($('span.selectBox-label:contains("Segmentation")')){
  console.log('selected');
}else{
   console.log('not selected');
}
```

this is my html

```
<a class="selectBox required selectBox-dropdown selecterror selectBox-menuShowing" tabindex="NaN">
    <span class="selectBox-label" style="width: 293px;">List Management</span>
    <span class="selectBox-arrow"></span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `$(selector)` will return a jQuery object, which will always be truthy. You can either check whether the length of the returned value is `> 0` or use `.is()` like

```
if ($('span.selectBox-label').is(':contains("Segmentation")')) {
    console.log('selected');
} else {
    console.log('not selected');
}
```

Also note that, using [:contains()](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) will return partial matches

Comment: nice... Is it possible, to execute this code every time text changes inside span ?

Comment: you will have to look at mutation observer/evetns

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
if($.trim(('span.selectBox-label').text()) == 'Segmentation' ){
```